# Puppeteer Wait for frame to be detached

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am wondering, using puppeteer how do I wait for a frame(using its name) to be detached from the page.
I can't get it to work by going through the official docs.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```js
while (!frame.isDetached()) await page.waitForTimeout(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually use for waiting. In this case, 3000 is milliseconds which is equal to 3 seconds.

```
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
```